# A sum over roots of a simple Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

The following question originates from analyzing the modular $S$-formation of a modular differential equation that annihilates the character of a chiral algebra. A term pops up that is proportional to the $M_{ij}$ matrix described below which should be diagonalized (it is by observation, but I want to prove it in general).

Consider a rank $r$ simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The roots are $\alpha$, the simple roots $\alpha_i$. Any root can be expanded as
$$
\alpha = \sum_{i = 1}^r m^\alpha_i \alpha_i \ .
$$
The Killing form $K(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2h^\vee}\operatorname{tr}_\mathbf{adj}XY$ induces an inner product $(\mu, \nu)$ for weights, which satisfy
$$
\sum_{\alpha} (\alpha, \mu) (\alpha, \nu) = 2h^\vee (\mu, \nu) \ .
$$
The norm-squared $|\alpha|^2:= (\alpha, \alpha)$ is such that long roots have $|\alpha|^2 = 2$. And $\alpha_i^\vee$ denotes the simple coroots.

By some direct **computations**, we notice the following: the matrix
$$
M_{ij} := \sum_{\alpha} m^\alpha_i |\alpha_i|^2 (\alpha, \alpha^\vee_j)^{2n + 1} \ , \qquad n = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
$$
is always **diagonal**. I have checked cases like $A_{1, 2, 3}, B_{4, 5}, C_6, D_5, F_4, G_2, E_{6,7,8}$, for $n = 0, 1,2, 3, ... 9$

**I hope to prove the above observation in general for all $\mathfrak{g}$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.**

The case with $n = 0$ is simple to prove. It just says
$$
\sum_{\alpha} (\alpha, \omega_i^\vee) |\alpha_i|^2 (\alpha, \alpha_j^\vee)
= 2h^\vee (\omega_i^\vee, \alpha_j^\vee) |\alpha_i|^2
= 2h^\vee (\omega_i^\vee, \alpha_j) \frac{2}{|\alpha_j|^2} |\alpha_i|^2 \\
= 2h^\vee \delta_{ij} \frac{2|\alpha_i|^2}{|\alpha_j|^2} \ .
$$
Here the first equality makes use of the previously mentioned property of the inner product. For $n > 0$, I don't known if similar formula exists (the question itself suggests some formula exists). If one were to write the inner product using Cartan-Weyl basis $H^I, E^\alpha$, then the equality seems to be related to some property of the trace
$$
\operatorname{tr}( H^I H^J H^K ...)
$$

Another way to approach the problem is to do it for ABCDEFG separately, utilizing the explicit root structure. But that's not what I want.

It feels like a simple thing to understand but at the moment I can't find a way. **I wonder how to prove that $M_{ij}$ is always (for all $\mathfrak{g}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$) diagonal? Or, if it is not always true, what is the criteria for it to be true?**

A snapshot of some checked cases
[image: Case checked]

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks, added context and some thoughts.

Comment: You're welcome. I have now upvoted :)

Comment: What is your question? You are asking "How this can be done", but what is "this?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan I clarify the question: how to prove $M_{ij}$ is diagonal.

Comment: It is better now, but what then do you mean by the statement "the matrix $(M_{ij})$ is **always** diagonal?" Do you mean that it is true for $n=0$ and all ${\mathfrak g}$'s? Then you should say so. Also, your last question should then include "for all $n>0$."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the suggestion. I added cases I checked and clarified the my question a bit more.

Comment: Curious, what software is that?

Comment: @BenWest Oh it's Mathematica 11 with custom stylesheet.